# Piping problems (Broken pipe)

Tags: c++, unix, pipe

Given a command in this format:

```
cat < inputfile.txt | tee outputfile.txt
```

I'm trying to have inputfile.txt write to a pipe and then have outputfile.txt read from the pipe, and I've written the following fucntions to do so:

```
void piperead(char** input, int* fd, int start) {

    dup2(fd[0], 0);
    close(fd[1]);
    execl("usr/bin/tee", "usr/bin/tee", input[start + 1], NULL);

}

void pipewrite(char** input, int* fd, int start, int end) {

    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(fd[0]);
    execl("usr/bin/cat", "usr/bin/tee", input[start + 2], NULL);

}

void dopiping(char** input, int start, int end) {

    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        cout << "Error: Pipe failed." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int pid = fork();
    switch(pid = fork()) {        
        case 0:
            piperead(input, fd, start, end);
        default:
            pipewrite(input, fd, end + 1);        
        case -1:
            exit(1);
    }


}
```

I've converted the command into an array of c_strings (let's call it cmdarray), and then I call dopiping(cmdarray, 0, 3). The moment the program gets to the line:

```
 dup2(fd[1], 1)
```

the program terminates because the program received SIGPIPE. Why is my pipe broken, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `"usr/bin/cat"` and not `"/usr/bin/cat"`?

Comment: Also, your program have a logical error: It will not continue after a successful `exec` call. Did you forget to `fork`?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to do "/usr/......". Do I use fork() in order to avoid the logical error?

Comment: If you read the [manual page for `execl(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) you will see that it "replaces the current process image with a new process image", and that the function does not return. You normally call [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a new process in which to do the `exec` call, which lets your main process continue running.

Comment: Alright, I forked in my dopiping() function, having the child read from the pipe and having the parent write to the pipe. My pipe is still broken, so I can't tell if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

So looking at this logically

- SIGPIPE is delivered to a process that does a write() to a closed or pipe/socket.
- Therefore the reading side of the pipe you create has to have been closed.
- Your code does not close `fd[0]` after you have performed your `dup2()`
- So it looks like the child process is exiting.
- I would guess that either the `execl()` is failing - you should try specifying "/usr/bin/tee" (full path not relative path)
- or your `tee` is failing - need to make sure that `input[start+1]` points to a null terminated string that represents a valid file path.